# Simple executable script to create playlist file for slideshow

Tags: batch-file

I'm a Mac user, but I need to write a script on Windows, and I'm not sure how I should go about that.

Here's the scenario:

Someone adds photos to a USB drive. The drive is then inserted into a digital picture frame.

In order for the photos to autoplay, a 'playlist.asb' file must be present on the drive. I want to create a script that can be clicked on and executed to auto create the playlist file based on the image files added to the USB. The script would do something like this:

1. Check if there are images in the 'slideshow' folder.
2. Check if file called 'playlist.alb' exists, if not create it. If so, overwrite it.
3. Loop through available images.
4. Add each image name and extension on a new line.
5. Save (and overwrite any existing playlist file) and exit.

I'm comfortable with AppleScript for Macs, but I'm not sure if a Windows equivalent would make sense, or if some kind of command line script would work better.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0Slideshow
if exist playlist.alb del playlist.alb
for %%a in (*.jpg *.gif *.png) do (
   echo %%~nxa>>playlist.alb
)
```

Comment: +1 The cd command assumes the slideshow folder is in the same folder where the batch file resides.